# Django django_admin_log' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

I have setup a new database with MySQL and run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

then run

```
python loaddata db.json
```

to load data from my previous sqlite database.

But now when I try to access the admin pages I get

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/
(1146, "Table 'myapp.django_admin_log' doesn't exist")
```

Other answers say to run syncdb but it not longer exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Add `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then run `python manage.py migrate admin` to create initial db tables for `admin` application. It will create `django_admin_log` table for you.